# create lables from bins

Tags: r, function, text, label

i am using the `cut` function, :

```
my_data[, ageGroup :=cut(my_data$age,
                         breaks = c(0, ageBins),
                         include.lowest=TRUE,
                         labels = ageBins)]
```

where

```
breaks
[1]  0  6 18 29 49 59 69 99
```

currently my labels are stored in a vector:

```
ageBins
[1]  6 18 29 49 59 69 99
```

I was wondering how can i create labels in a functional way such that they indicate the intervals: 0-6, 6-18, 29-49, etc?

I a using the split function afterwards,

```
setNames(split(my_data, my_data$ageGroup), 
         unique(my_data$ageGroup))
```

and want the lists to be name with the corresponding intervals.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your desired output exactly? labels in a plot? or in a new column in a data frame? you should also provide some dummy data.so we can better help you figure out how to get where you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use paste consecutive `breaks` together.

```
ageBins <- c(6, 18, 29, 49, 59, 69, 99)
breaks = c(0, ageBins)
labels <- paste(breaks[-length(breaks)], breaks[-1], sep = '-')
#Also another way
#labels <- paste(head(breaks, -1), tail(breaks, -1), sep = '-')

labels
#[1] "0-6"   "6-18"  "18-29" "29-49" "49-59" "59-69" "69-99"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `zoo::rollapply`, but you would need to pass it `breaks` or initialize the value in `ageBins` to be `0`:

```
library(zoo)

zoo::rollapply(breaks, width = 2, FUN = function(x) paste(x, collapse = "-"))
[1] "0-18"  "18-29" "29-49" "49-59" "59-69" "69-99"
```

---

Or using the function `runner` from the same named library:

```
library(runner)

runner::runner(breaks, function(x) paste(x, collapse = "-"), k = 2)[-1]
[1] "0-18"  "18-29" "29-49" "49-59" "59-69" "69-99"
```